# SIM7000 modem slow to receive follow-up data

Tags: c++, serialization, memory-leaks, arduino, iot

I am adding onto the Botletics SIM7000 library. I can send data just fine but sometimes it takes forever to arrive. In the example below I send new messages as soon as I see the previous message show up in the serial monitor. There is one SEND at the end where I wait 60 seconds between messages and it arrives almost instantly. This is not an outlier. If I wait a long time the next message usually arrives quickly.

I am by no means an expert in C++. Is there somewhere that's bottlenecking my code or I'm dealing with closing the previous connection incorrectly? I want to be able to send data every few seconds and have it received and output.

I attached a copy of my loop, library addition, and a serial log that includes the millis() of when a message

Simple Arduino loop:

```
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 1000; // rapid but not constant polling

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    if (modem.available() > 0) {
      Serial.print("Dropped into the IF at: ");
      Serial.println(currentMillis);
      String message = modem.handleClientConnected();
      Serial.println(message);
      unsigned long nowIts = 0;
        nowIts = millis();
        Serial.print("Now its:");
        Serial.println(nowIts);
          unsigned long diff = 0;
          diff = nowIts - currentMillis;
          Serial.print("For a diff of (ms): ");
          Serial.println(diff);
      delay(50);
      modem.handleClientDisconnected();
    }
  }
}
```

BotleticsSIM7000.cpp:

```
String Botletics_modem::handleClientConnected() {
    String buffer;
    String message;
    const String startDelimiter = "REMOTE IP";
    const String endDelimiter = "}}}"; // this used to be "\EOT" but I need to the end of the string to be part of the JSON
    bool isMessageStarted = false;    // is it graceful? no. does it work for me for now. yes.


    while (this->available()) {
        char ch = this->read();
        buffer += ch;

        delay(3); // add the smallest amount of time to let the buffer fill. it will fail otherwise.

        if (!isMessageStarted) {

            if (ch == '\n') {
                if (buffer.startsWith(startDelimiter)) {
                    isMessageStarted = true;
                    buffer = ""; // Clear the buffer
                } else {
                    buffer = ""; // Reset buffer if start delimiter not found
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (buffer.endsWith(endDelimiter)) {
                int eotIndex = buffer.lastIndexOf(endDelimiter);
                // message = buffer.substring(0, eotIndex); // this used to trunk the EOT off the end of the string. I need it to be part of the JSON
                message = buffer;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

Serial log:

```
    [...]
    <--- OK
    <--- SERVER OK

Setup is complete @ 8736
Dropped into the IF at: 46743
firstmsg}}}
Now its:46903
For a diff of (ms): 160
    ---> AT+CIPSTATUS
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CIPCLOSE
    <--- CLOSE OK
Dropped into the IF at: 81743
secondmsg}}}
Now its:81907
For a diff of (ms): 164
    ---> AT+CIPSTATUS
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CIPCLOSE
    <--- CLOSE OK
Dropped into the IF at: 116743
thirdmsg}}}
Now its:116904
For a diff of (ms): 161
    ---> AT+CIPSTATUS
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CIPCLOSE
    <--- CLOSE OK
Dropped into the IF at: 151743
bigfourthmessage98298298237987238649878237987238649878237987238649873698}}}
Now its:152172
For a diff of (ms): 429
    ---> AT+CIPSTATUS
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CIPCLOSE
    <--- CLOSE OK
Dropped into the IF at: 186743
fifthmsg}}}
Now its:186904
For a diff of (ms): 161
    ---> AT+CIPSTATUS
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CIPCLOSE
    <--- CLOSE OK
Dropped into the IF at: 251743
sixthmessagewitha60seconddelaybetweenseeinglastandsendingthis}}}
Now its:252126
For a diff of (ms): 383
    ---> AT+CIPSTATUS
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CIPCLOSE
    <--- CLOSE OK
Dropped into the IF at: 287743
rapidfollow}}}
Now its:287916
For a diff of (ms): 173
    ---> AT+CIPSTATUS
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CIPCLOSE
    <--- CLOSE OK
Dropped into the IF at: 322743
eigth}}}
Now its:322891
For a diff of (ms): 148
    ---> AT+CIPSTATUS
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CIPCLOSE
    <--- CLOSE OK
```

Comment: No idea what `modem.handleClientDisconnected();` does, but from its name, it seems that your client disconnect from the server every time its received ONE message instead of keeping the connection for all the message communication.